# Assign value to dataframe inside parent environment

Tags: r

I have a parent function (`fun1`) that takes `data` and a helper function (`fun2`) that operates on columns from that `data`.  I want to assign the value from that helper function to it's matching column in `data` in `fun1`.  In reality there are lots of little helper functions operating on columns and I want the value changed by `fun2` to be what the other helper functions deal with.

**How can I take the outout from `fun2` and assign it to the matching column of `data` in `fun1`?**  I do not want to make that alteration to `data` in `fun1` but want to change `data` from within `fun2`.

```
fun1 <- function(data){

    Map(fun2, data, colnames(data))

    data[[1]]
}

fun2 <- function(x, colname_x){

    x <- x * 2

    # my attempt to assign to `data[["mpg"]]`
    assign(sprintf("data[[\"%s\"]]", colname_x), value=x, pos = 1)

}


fun1(mtcars[1:3])
```

**Desired output of `fun1`:**

```
##  [1] 42.0 42.0 45.6 42.8 37.4 36.2 28.6 48.8 45.6 38.4 35.6 32.8 34.6 30.4 20.8
## [16] 20.8 29.4 64.8 60.8 67.8 43.0 31.0 30.4 26.6 38.4 54.6 52.0 60.8 31.6 39.4
## [31] 30.0 42.8
```

***EDIT:*** Also tried:

```
fun2 <- function(x, colname_x = "mpg"){
    x <- x * 2
    assign(sprintf("data[[\"%s\"]]", colname_x), value=x, env = parent.frame(3))
}
```

***Edit 2***  This works but seems not so clean:
'

```
fun2 <- function(x, colname_x = "mpg"){

    x <- x * 2
    data <- get('data', env=parent.frame(3))
    data[[colname_x]] <- x
    assign('data', value=data, env = parent.frame(3))

}
```

Comment: Why is functional programming, i.e., returning results and assigning as usual, not good enough for this?

Comment: Aside - it's good to see high rep folks still asking questions on SO.

Comment: @Roland fair question.  Simply, I can.  This is more a question of how to do this; a learning of assigning to fames in other environments.  Not so much a what's the best way.

Comment: Fair enough. Anyway, you can't assign to `data[["mpg"]]` with `assign`. You must assign to `data`, i.e., copy the whole data.frame.